# Checking which distributions are infinitely divisible

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I have got this homework to check which distributions with the following characteristic functions are infinitely divisible:

- $\frac{1}{1-it}$
- $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$
- $e^{-t^2}\cos t $

I literally have no idea how to approach it. All I know is the definition of infinite divisibility. Could you show me how to deal with tasks like that?

The definition I was given at the lecture:

Distribution of random variable $X$ is infinitely divisible if for every $n \in N$ there exist $X_{1,n},.., X_{n,n}$ i.i.d such that $X \stackrel{D}{=} X_{1,n}+\cdots+X_{n,n}$

Comment: "All I know is the definition of infinite divisibility"  Then you know more than I do.  Please share.

Comment: Sory I should have done that in the first place. I've edited my question.

Comment: Do you know the characteristic function of the sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables? Can you reverse this and check whether you still have a characteristic function?

Comment: So the characteristic function of the sum of n i.i.d. random variables is the characteristic function of $X_1$  to the nth power, but what do you mean by reversing?

Comment: Reversing the $n$th power would be taking the $n$th root.  So for example is $\sqrt[n]{ \frac{1}{1-it}}$ a characteristic function? If it is for all $n$ then the first example is infinitely divisible, and if not then not. It may help if you know the characteristic functions of some common distributions

Comment: In general, determining whether a function is a characteristic function is a hard problem, Maybe some of the methods in this answer are helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2417928/177399

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to give hints when possible:

1. $\frac1{1-it}$ is the c.f. of a famous distribution. Furthermore, that distribution is part of a $2$-parameter family of distributions with nice additive properties, which allows you to show it is infinitely divisible (i.d.). For example, any normal distribution  is i.d. because $N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)\oplus N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$. A similar relation holds for family containing the random variable with this ch.f.
2. You can leverage the answer for $1$ to get an answer for $2$. Note that $\phi_2(t):=1/(1+t^2)$ is the complex modulus of $\phi_1(t):=1/(1-it)$. This means that $\phi_2(t)=\phi_1(t)\overline{\phi_1(t)}$, which further implies that $X_2\stackrel{d}=X_1-X_1'$, where $X_1$ has ch.f. $\phi_1$, $X_2$ has ch.f. $\phi_2$, and $X_1'$ is an iid copy of $X_1$.
3. There is a well-known theorem that the characteristic function of an infinitely divisible distribution cannot have any zeroes, which rules out this function. For a proof, see [this MSE annswer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/416436/177399).